# FullCalendar not displaying the calendar

Tags: jquery, reactjs, fullcalendar

i downloaded a template that contains a Calendar with events but when i tried to integrate it to use it for my react application the fullcalendar is not showing the calendar while when i open the downloaded template it works fine but when i took the html and js files and used them it didn't work and didn't know how to solve this problem i don't think the react can cause problems

the HTML PART :

```
            <div class="col-lg-9">
              <div class="card-body b-l calender-sidebar">
                         <div id="calendar">
                         </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

the Js files are :

```
    <script src="HomeCSS/assets/libs/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="HomeCSS/assets/libs/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="HomeCSS/dist/js/pages/calendar/cal-init.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is your react implementation code?

Comment: i didn't write any code in the component i just rendered html that's it

Comment: Did you include the CSS files? Do you get any errors in your console? What version of fullCalendar are you using? What does your call-init.js code do? There's no way we can work out your problem from the incomplete information you've given us so far.

Comment: P.s. did you know that the latest version of fullCalendar had a ready made react component to make integration easier? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react

Comment: i thought that version does not comport a version with add and remove events and also using drag and drop and btw the problem is solved i added type="module" in my <script src="HomeCSS/dist/js/pages/calendar/cal-init.js"></script>

Comment: "thought that version does not comport a version with add and remove events"...why not? What makes you think that? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-remove. There are other ways of adding and removing events too, using event sources. Not sure how you got the idea you couldn't add/remove events?? That would be pretty useless for a calendar!

Comment: @ADyson i meant the calendar that i found in the template is kinda complete but still thank you for that link i could use it someday